# Random number with uniform distribution over a long period

Tags: java, random

I would like to generate (quality) random numbers in my Java EE application over a long period of time (dozens of numbers per day). It should keep the uniform distribution even if the server is restarted etc. Do you have any recommendation as to how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Uncommons Maths](http://blog.uncommons.org/2007/11/19/announcing-uncommons-maths/) is a library that offers some RNGs that are more robust than those in the jdk

Answer (score 2):

All of the methods in `java.util.Random` return a uniform distribution of random numbers except for [nextGaussian()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextGaussian%28%29).

As far as not generating predictable sequences of random numbers, Why not just set the seed to the time of day in milliseconds XORed with the current process id?

Comment: +1: The current process id is tricky to get, however the System.nanoTime() is not and the Random() uses this as part of its default seed. If you want a less predictable sequence you can use SecureRandom.

Comment: Yeah, it's not portable.  You can use JMX but its platform dependent.  Argh!  Write a JNI routine I suppose.  The C programmer inside of me is disgusted with this.

Comment: @Peter: +1 on using SecureRandom. @Amir: Making up your own method of non-guessable random numbers (or, more generally, your own anything cryptography related) is almost always a bad idea.